# JsonWriter IOException Incomplete Document

Tags: java, json, ioexception

I'm using a com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter with a StringWriter to write a somewhat long JSON.

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(stringWriter);
```

Then iterating over a collection and writing the JSON.

```
jsonWriter.name("Elements").beginArray();
Collection<Element> collection = someObject.getCollection();
    for(Element e : collection){
        jsonWriter.beginObject()
            .name("Id").value(e.getId())
        .endObject();
    }
jsonWriter.endArray();
```

My problem is that when I try to close the writer I get an **IOException: Incomplete Document.** And it seems that the stream fails to flush all the data or something because the JSON ends in the middle of an element.

Like this:

```
{
    "Id": "1245
```

The Collection is in fact a **HashMap.values()**. I have a hunch that it's because a HashMap is not synchronized or something of that sort.

Edit: I'm closing the writer and getting the string this way:

```
jsonWriter.flush();
jsonWriter.close();
String json = stringWriter.toString();
```

Comment: Please give a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Stupid mistake on my behalf. 

I had other code writing above the list and I was missing an endObject()... I was developing for Android and the LogCat has a limit of characters so when I printed out the string it would look like as if the writer didn't finish to flush or something.

Note to self, count the beginObject()s and endObject()s, at least 3 times!!

Sorry for the was of time.

Comment: I messed up too, and didn't have an endObject(). Thanks for posting your comment.